# Cannot debug native Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem object from code

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging a VSTO Outlook Add-in and I would like to inspect what is the content for an [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia) object. When I add it to watch window in Visual Studio I get below message within the object:

[image]

Then I enable native code debugging but when I start the VSTO Outlook Add-in from Visual Studio I get below exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA5355FCBC in OUTLOOK.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: windows_exception_impl<0> at memory location 0x000000000014E3A8.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA5355FCBC in OUTLOOK.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: windows_exception_impl<0> at memory location 0x000000000014E3A8.
'OUTLOOK.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
OUTLOOK.EXE has triggered a breakpoint.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA57B81083 (ntdll.dll) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC00000AA: An attempt was made to execute an instruction at an unaligned address and the host system does not support unaligned instruction references.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA57C68404 (ntdll.dll) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA57B81083 (ntdll.dll) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC00000AA: An attempt was made to execute an instruction at an unaligned address and the host system does not support unaligned instruction references.
```

If I click on continue it does not work, the exception don't stop appearing indefinitely. So is there any way I can debug it?

Note: I am using traditional NET Framework 4.5 and the add-in is compiled as AnyCPU on a 64-bit Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem` object is implemented in C++ by Outlook itself. Unless you have Outlook source code, there is nothing you can do. And why would you want to? Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve?